# google bigquery c# API enum

Tags: c#, enums, google-bigquery

I'm trying to work with bigquery, its c# API and complex types.

I have an object like

```
public class MyObject
{
    public MyOtherObject SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MyOtherObject
{
    public string InnerProperty { get; set; }

    public MyEnum OtherInnerProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The field in the table corresponding to MyOtherObject is a `RECORD`, with an InnerProperty `STRING` field and an OtherInnerProperty also `STRING` field.

working with `TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData`, when I try to "map" in the `Json` property (which is actually a `Dictionary<string,object>`) the property MyOtherObject with the corresponding field, an error is thrown because (I assume) OtherInnerProperty, which is an enum, cannot be converted to string.

Any idea how to deal with enums in that particular case ?

Thanks.

EDIT: obviously I can have the field corresponding to "OtherInnerProperty" as an INTEGER field in the BQ table, but I'd rather have to OtherInnerProperty.ToString() and get that STRING value in my table...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've solved the issue, but I also had this problem and I solved it as follows:

When you create the service in:

```
var service = new BigqueryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
             {
                 HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                 ApplicationName = applicationName
             });
```

Add `Serializer = new EnumToStringNewtonsoftJsonSerializer()`, where EnumToStringNewtonsoftJsonSerializer is a modification of Google.Apis.Json.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer that can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Core/Apis/Json/NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.cs?name=1.8.1

In the constructor of EnumToStringNewtonsoftJsonSerializer put:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings(); 
settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore; 
settings.Converters.Add(new RFC3339DateTimeConverter()); 
settings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
newtonsoftSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
```

This worked for me.